# Can ImageMagicK use dialog based MFC windows application?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, image-processing, imagemagick

I'm trying to use ImageMagicK on vs2010.
Can ImageMagicK use dialog based MFC windows application?

If yes,  how to apply these ImageMagicK initialize code into dialog based MFC windows application?

Comment: You have to call `InitializeMagick` once before using any ImageMagick object. As to command line arguments, there are many example on how to parse them in MFC applications

Comment: @Sga : but there is no main() or argv. I can make some example MFC project

Comment: Have you used the Application Wizard to create your application? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/64c73803.aspx

Comment: @Sga : I have tried with ParseCommandLine but I think I am doing something wrong.